# Multiple resizes using a single image read/stream

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I'm writing a script that takes an image and creates multiple variants of different sizes (like imgur, basically). Right now, I do the following for each variant using https://github.com/aheckmann/gm in node.js:

```
function(file, size, newfile, callback) {
  gm(file)
    .noProfile()
    .quality(80)
    .resize(size, size)
    .write(newfile, callback)
}
```

1. I assume that each time I resize the image, graphicsmagick reads the image form the disk and loads it into memory. Is this correct? If so, how can I make read from disk only once?
2. Can I read the file from a stream, then run multiple resizes on a single stream? I don't know enough about streams, and when I tried doing this last, I got frustrated, gave up, and deleted that portion of the code.

Comment: nope. i just store it as a buffer for now: https://github.com/discore/image-resize-s3

Comment: just as an aside: doing this would kill your memory, so it's not advisable if you're on a low memory platform like heroku. you're betting off using mpc files: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#mpc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two *commandline* examples how to do it with ImageMagick.

They use the `mpr:` syntax supported by ImageMagick, which tells ImageMagick to temporarily save the input image into a named *memory program register*, from which it can later (while processing) read the data much faster than it could do from harddisk.

- [**Splitting image with ImageMagick**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11940078/359307)
- [**Efficiently generating thumbnails with ImageMagick and convert**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12688856/359307)

It should be easy for you to translate these commandlines into [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) parlance.